# Illustrations showing up pixelated in Indesign despite huge resolution

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, resolution, illustration, digital-printing

Illustrations I create in Procreate show up pixelated at edges despite high resolution when I place them in Indesign.

[image: illustrations' edges have some odd black outline around them]

I'm working on illustrating books for print. It's my first time working on a print project, I usually do digital illustration for the web.

I use Procreate on Ipad Pro for illustrations, and need to place them into Indesign layouts. I do my best to create clean lines in my illustrations, and use a huge resolution as well (each illustration is about 3000x3000px in size), but when I place them in Indesign there's some weird stuff happening with illustration edges. I use 4000x4000 at 300dpi resolution for my canvas. Then export the image as PNG before placing into Indesign.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe it's exactly because the resolution is too high? Or it's a PNG issue?

Answer (score 9):

Nothing wrong, is just the Indesign **Typical Display Image**.

Select the image > Go to menu **Object** > **Display Performance** > **High Quality Display**

The **Typical Display Image** is to work faster with the application, having a book with many images and all at High Quality Display would reduce the work speed.

[image: display]

Comment: This literally saved my grade for a class thank you sm!